# Regex to find value inside background url tag

Tags: asp.net, css, regex

1. I have `"$('#tab1').css("background-image", "url(../CARImages/Icons/tab1.png)");"`
   I need to extract `"../CARImages/Icons/tab1.png"` from this.
2. I may have `"background-image:url(../Images/Themes/tile_bg.png);"` syntax in css.
   I need to extract `"../Images/Themes/tile_bg.png"` from this.

Can I have same Regex for both the above syntax to extract image reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the regex `(?<=url\().*?(?=\))`. It will match text between the first `url(` in the string and the first `)` after that.

You can find an explanation and demonstration here: http://regex101.com/r/qP9mX6

Comment: Hi while i am trying to get ../Images/bg_topnav.gif from background:url("../Images/bg_topnav.gif"), I am also getting inverted comas. But I dont want inverted comas. just the value inside the brackets like ../Images/bg_topnav.gif.

Can you please modify the Regex, so that all the above 3 conditions gets satisfied.